# AngularJS component bindings not passing object

Tags: angularjs, angular-components

Receiving error cannot read property 'type' of undefined at PollListCtrl.runQuery.
I'm not sure why this is coming up undefined. I've console logged profile-polls.controller.js where listConfig is created to make sure there is an object here. The response is

```
{type: "all", filters: {pollsCreated: Array(3)}}
```

But it is coming up undefined when I try to pass it to poll-list component in the profile-polls.html. Below is the gist for the relevant files. Can anyone tell me why this is not passing correctly?

https://gist.github.com/RawleJuglal/fa668a60e88b6f7a95b456858cf20597

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on line 57, is queryConfig undefined?

Comment: My debug skills aren't strong so I'm not sure how to breakpoint looking at it in chrome, but I did a console log of queryConfig before this._Polls.query but it does not get that far. I assume because it is throwing the error at line 41.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to define watcher for your component. On start `listConfig` is undefined and only after some delay (next digest cycle) it gets value. So we create watcher and cancel it after `if` statement.

```
app.component('pollList', {
  bindings: {
    listConfig: '='
  },
  templateUrl: 'poll-list.html',
  controllerAs: 'vm',
  controller: PollListCtrl
});

function PollListCtrl($scope) {

    var vm = this;

    function run(){
      console.log(vm.listConfig);
    }


    var cancelWatch = $scope.$watch(function () {
        return vm.listConfig;
    },
    function (newVal, oldVal) {

        if (newVal !== undefined){
            run();
            cancelWatch();
        }
    });
}
```

<kbd>[Demo plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/hyD4JKOHjoUhjEyXcb1N?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: Sorry tried this but no change. It was also my understanding that controllerAs in the config would do the same thing. Is that not the case?

Answer (score 0):

- You should never use $scope in your angularjs application.
- You can use ngOnInit() life cycle hook to access "bindings" value instead constructor.

  ngOnInit(){

  $ctrl.listConfig = { type: 'all' };

  $ctrl.limit = 5;

  }